# How can i make the lose label to appear once the timer hits zero?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, sprite-kit

I'm a beginner in coding and I need help in the following code. I'm trying to make the "You Lose!" label appear after the timer hits zero, but when I try to do it; it doesn't show anything. Please help me!

```
class Game: SKScene {

    let Ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Red.png")
    var QuitOption = SKLabelNode()
    var ScoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
    var timesecond = Int(60)
    var locked = false
    var loseOption = SKLabelNode()
    var winOption = SKLabelNode()
    let whiteBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "whiteDot")
    let showMessage = SKLabelNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


        backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor() // background for the display

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -9.8)

        let SceneBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        SceneBody.friction = 0
        self.physicsBody = SceneBody


        Ball.size = CGSize(width: 82, height: 82)
        Ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height*0.1)
        Ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 42)
        Ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        Ball.physicsBody?.density = 10
        Ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.1
        Ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        Ball.name = "Ball"

        self.addChild(Ball)

        QuitOption.text = "Quit"
        QuitOption.fontName = "Noteworthy-Light"
        QuitOption.fontColor = SKColor.redColor()
        QuitOption.fontSize = 35
        QuitOption.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2 - 160, y: self.frame.size.height*1 - 110)
        QuitOption.name = "Quit"

        addChild(QuitOption)

        ScoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Noteworthy-Light")
        ScoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor.redColor()
        ScoreLabel.fontSize = 35                 // The + will move it to the right side and - to the left side for more accuracy.
        ScoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2 + 160, y: self.frame.size.height/1 - 115) // position of ScoreLabelNode
        ScoreLabel.name = "Score+"
        ScoreLabel.hidden = false

        self.addChild(ScoreLabel)

        whiteBall.size = CGSize(width: 55, height: 55)
        whiteBall.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height*0.8)
        whiteBall.name = "whiteBall"

        self.addChild(whiteBall)

        showMessage.fontName = "Noteworthy-Light"
        showMessage.fontSize = 55
        showMessage.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        showMessage.text = "YOU LOSE!"
        showMessage.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height*0.7)
        showMessage.zPosition = 100
        showMessage.hidden = true
        showMessage.name = "show Message"


        self.addChild(showMessage)


    }

    // Making the ball jump after user touches ball

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {


        var touch = touches.first as! UITouch
        var location = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)
        // var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)


        if (node.name == "Quit"){

            let myScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
            myScene.scaleMode = scaleMode
            let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
            self.view?.presentScene(myScene, transition: reveal)

        }

        if (node.name == "Ball"){

            for touch: AnyObject in touches {

                let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

                Ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
                Ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
                Ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 450))

            }


        }



        if(!self.locked){



            self.locked = true

        var actionrun = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)

        var actionwait = SKAction.runBlock({


            self.timesecond--


            if self.timesecond == 60 {self.timesecond = 0}

            self.ScoreLabel.text = "\(self.timesecond)"})

            let loopAction = SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence([actionwait, actionrun]), count: 60)

            ScoreLabel.runAction(loopAction, withKey: "scoreAction")

            if (timesecond == 0){

                showMessage.hidden = false

            }


        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
    if (timesecond == 0){

        showMessage.hidden = false

    }
```

... should be in the block that runs every second:

```
var actionwait = SKAction.runBlock({


    self.timesecond--

    if self.timesecond == 60 {self.timesecond = 0}

    self.ScoreLabel.text = "\(self.timesecond)"

    if (self.timesecond == 0){

        showMessage.hidden = false

    }
})

let loopAction = SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence([actionwait, actionrun]), count: 60)

ScoreLabel.runAction(loopAction, withKey: "scoreAction")
```